# Problem using a tikzpicture in \titleformat

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, titlesec

I'm trying to customize the style of my chapter headings with `tikz`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to properly use `tikz` in the (optional) `⟨after⟩` argument of the the `\titleformat` command. With the minimal example below, my compiler seems to get lost in an endless loop; the `⟨after⟩` argument has to be the culprit because, if I remove it, I don't run into any trouble. Any idea of what's going wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang]
{\huge}
{}
{0em}
{}
[\large \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);\end{tikzpicture}]
% the previous line does not work when [ultra thick] is included

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Don't use a `tikzpicture` environment here. Use the inline version instead: `\tikz{\draw [ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the parsing of optional arguments. LaTeX reads `\titleformat{\chapter} ... [` and finds a bracket: the optional argument starts. And per definition the next closing bracket will close the optional argument. So the argument (excluding surrounding brackets will be `\large \vbox{\begin{tikzpicture} \draw [ultra thick`, which is obviously not want we think it should be. The trick here is to hide the `]` from LaTeX by enclosing the whole argument (or the relevant part, i.e. the `{tikzpicture}`) in braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang]
{\huge}
{}
{0em}
{}
[\large {\begin{tikzpicture} \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);\end{tikzpicture}}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Works fine …