# Use (remember picture, overlay) TikZ picture to design parts, chapters, ToC, Bibliography, Index

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, positioning, chapters, parts

### What I have

I am designing the format of the parts and chapters in my document using Ti*k*Z picture, with `remember picture, overlay` option, like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{bggray}{RGB}{215,215,215}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[below right=4.8cm and 0cm of current page.north east] (a) {};
    \fill[bggray] (current page.north west) rectangle (a);
    \node[below right=1cm and 2cm of current page.north west,color=blue!90] {\huge\bfseries Part I};
    \node[below right=2.5cm and 2cm of current page.north west,color=blue]{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\scshape Foundations};
    \node[below left=1cm and 3cm of current page.north east] (pic1) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{0.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### What I want

Now I have some problems:

1. **Overall customization** I want to use this design for *all* parts and chapters (actually in chapters I will change a bit in colors and sizes). This should satisfy

   - The commands to use the design, like `\part{}` and `\chapter{}` in normal design, should be used simply. I prefer something like

     ```
     \mypart{Foundations}{abc.jpg}
     \mychapter{Foundations}{abc.jpg}
     ```
   - The parts and chapters should be numbered as usual.
   - There should be contents referring to the parts/chapter in the Table of Contents, and if I use `hyperref` package, the ToC contents should be clickable.
2. **The Table of Contents, Bibliography, Index, etc. should be of the same design.** In other word, I want

   ```
   \tableofcontents
   ```

   to be as

   ```
   \mychapter*{Table of Contents}{} % There will be no pictures included
   ```

   and to output the result

   [image]

   by using `\tableofcontents` only.

---

### Some remarks

I have read this question: [Problem using a tikzpicture in \titleformat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148533/problem-using-a-tikzpicture-in-titleformat), but that is not what I mean, *because the question is about normal Ti*k*Z picture in title design, but **not** about `remember picture, overlay` Ti*k*Z picture in title design.*

You can either help me to solve my problem, or edit the accepted answer in the attached question so that it suits the requirements well.

All your helps will be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

---

### Edit 2

Following @marmot's answer, and the answer actually almost help me solve the issue. However, the ToC became

```
Chapter 0
CONTENTS
```

How to delete `Chapter 0`?

Comment: May be you are interested in this blog article series about a complete book design. It's based in `memoir` but will give you an idea about the process. See: http://latex-my.blogspot.com/search/label/bookdesign

Comment: Try with this one. It provides a template with all code and makes reference to original posts: http://liantze.penguinattack.org/latextypesetting.html#bookdesign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt. As for instance explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256633/121799), by loading the `titlesec` package with the `explicit` key, you can make the title part of a `tikzpicture`, which can of course be an `overlay`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}


\titleformat{\part}
{}
{}
{0em}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[below right=4.8cm and 0cm of current page.north east] (a) {};
    \fill[bggray] (current page.north west) rectangle (a);
    \node[below right=1cm and 2cm of current page.north west,color=blue!90]
    {\huge\bfseries Part \thepart};
    \node[below right=2.5cm and 2cm of current page.north
    west,color=blue]{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\scshape #1};
    \node[below left=1cm and 3cm of current page.north east] (pic1)
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\definecolor{bggray}{RGB}{215,215,215}
\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}

Some text

\part{More stuff}
\end{document}
```